# Razor view getting null pointer error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Having a brain-dead moment here.  I'm getting the NullReferenceException on Line 4, but I don't see how that is possible.  In debug mode, the model object is showing as null.  But the first condition in line 4, model != null, should've caused it to return false and stopped it from testing it further.

```
Line 3:  @{MessagesModel model = CCManager.getMessagesModel();}
Line 4:  @{bool hasError = (model != null && model.Messages != null && model.Messages.Count() > 0);}
```

Comment: NullReferenceException is not the same thing as a null pointer. Getting an exception about a null pointer would take a serious flaw in the .NET codebase.

Comment: When it comes to Razor views, the line highlighting for errors is not always spot on. It doesn't look like you have any issues here, so I would check the code behind `CCManager.getMessagesModel()` and also lines of your Razor view around this.

Comment: what if you write it like this: @{bool hasError = model?.Messages?.Count() > 0;}

Comment: It seems like a scope problem.  The view does not seem to know model variable exist on Line 4.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and examine the variables to see what is null.